# Vue Render JQuery Plugin Upon v-if Set to True On Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, vue.js, vuejs2, icheck

I have a checkbox that is being styled by [iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/), a JQuery plugin. The checkbox has a v-if directive, which will be set to true by a JQuery Post request.

```
function initializeICheck() {
    $('input').iCheck({
  checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
  radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
  increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});
}

var login = new Vue({
  el: '#vLogin',
  data: {
    showcheckbox: false,
  },
  methods: {
    validateLogin: function() {
        $.post("validate", function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        }).done(function(response) {
            login.showcheckbox = true;
            initializeICheck();
        });
    }
  }
});
```

However, when the validateLogin method is being called, the checkbox appears, but the call to function doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how do I properly render the checkbox styling?

Comment: if you call the function initializeICheck directly as first statement inside validateLogin, does it work?

Comment: You need a [wrapper component](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html)

Comment: @V.Sambor no it doesn't

Comment: Then it means it has nothing to do with the ajax call, you just have to fix the display of ICheck

Comment: no, if you check the description above, the checkbox is rendered after the JQuery Post request so the iCheck should be initialized after. If I went to DevTools > Console and run initializeICheck(), the checkbox would be styled.